# What is the most suitable database to use with mobile application

Tags: android

I am developing an android mobile application in java. Even though i have read about SQLite and how you should select what database to use. I am not sure if it is the appropriate database to use for my application. I need to store and retrieve Login details of users, weather information, location of user etc. Is SQLite the most appropriate database for this?

Comment: There is no other database in mobile except SQLite, I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In android , for persistant storage you have 3 options (you can save it in network, but I'm only considering about saving in mobile itself).

- Shared Preference
- Files (Internal and External)
- SQLite database

Shared preference can mostly be used for saving small key value storage. For large amount of data you will have to use SQLite database, much better option than files. See android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) on the topic

## About other database

Android native support is only for SQLite database. If you want to use other database schemes, you might have to rely on any other 3rd party libraries which are specifically built for android.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I have any other options? Can I use MySQL with java?

Comment: MySQL will not run on your Android device, so you'd have to connect to a remote server for this, assuming you can use mysql client libraries on android. Even then, it means your application would not work if not connected. Even worse, you'd have to somehow store the database password in your app, leaving it open for attack by ill-intentioned users !

Answer (score 0):

You should start with SQLite and in future move to any Database/Datacenter which u think feasible.

I recommend to use Cloud based Datacenters for Android Applications.